# show that for any real number x with x>0 there is a p integer s.t. $1/(2^p)<x$

Tags: real-analysis

show that for any real number x with x>0 there is a p integer s.t. $1/(2^p)<x$. Hint use the fact that R is an Archimedean field...I don't know how to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First try inverting the problem, so that you're trying to find $p$ such that $2^p>\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Hint: if $n>1$ then $2^n>n $.   Think about what Archimedian means.